# Missing return type in uml class

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, return-type

I have to write the java code corresponding the following class diagram:
[image]

what about missing informations about visibility and return type of methods? Is the visibility understood as 'package'? Is the return type understood as 'void'?

Comment: Well let me ask you that. What should a method such as `deposit` return, if anything?

Comment: I think it could be reasonably void… but considering that we don't know who wrote the diagram ad how he defined that method, is there something 'standard' about missing return type?

Comment: @GBlodgett It could return the new balance. Who knows?

Comment: @ThomasKilian Exactly. It could also return a boolean in the case that there are insufficient funds. Or maybe it would throw an error in that case. Or it would assume you've already checked to make sure there are enough funds and it'd be void. It all depends on the design of the program

Answer (score 6):

On p. 53 of UML 2.5 (section 7.8.12 PackageableElement):

> A PackageableElement must have a visibility specified if it is owned by a Namespace. The default visibility is public.

On p. 116 of UML 2.5 (section 9.6 Operations):

> `<return-type>` is the type of the return result Parameter if the Operation has one defined.

So in Cxx-terms that would be `void`.